# One to Many Relationship Over Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have existing data in the database, and I want to create a one-to-many relationship. How can I limit or simulate a one-to-many relationship when I'm using a pivot table?

I want to get the data from the pivot table, so I thought it could be done like this.

```
class Asset extends Model {
    public function publisher() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Publisher::class, 'asset_publisher');
    }
}
```

-

```
class Publisher extends Model {
    public function assets() {
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class, 'asset_publisher');
    }
}
```

Comment: can't understand the starting problem... can you please explain better what's the problem? also, please post the controller or the method where you are trying to do this, but with the hasmany relation, so the code that you are saying that it's not working

Comment: I have multiple unassigned assets. I want to assign the existing assets to a publisher, but each asset should only have one publisher. Since I'm using Laravel Nova, the closest thing I have to a controller is, `BelongsToMany::make('publishers')->nullable()->searchable(),`

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to simulate the one-to-many is creating a model for the pivot table "AssetPublisher" so you will now have

```
    class Publisher extends Model {

        public function assets() {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Asset::class, 'asset_publisher');
        }
    }


   class AssetPublisher extends Model {

        public function publisher() {
            return $this->belongsTo(Publisher::class);
        }
    }

   class Asset extends Model {

        public function assetPublisher() {
            return $this->hasOne(AssetPublisher::class)->with('publisher');
        }

        public function getPublisherAttribute(){
            return $this->assetPublisher->publisher;
        }
    }
```

You can now call `$asset->publisher` to give you the Publisher instance and `$publisher->assets()->get()` to get all assets instances